# ozie scheduling hive SemanticException Unable to determine if hdfs://namenode:8020/xxx is encrypted

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I am a Chinese and my English level is very poor, so there may be mistakes in grammar.Thank you for the first.

When I use oozie scheduling hive,oozie no error.But when I select from a table in hive CLI, there is a error like that

```
parse.CalcitePlanner (SemanticAnalyzer.java:getMetaData(1849)) - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to determine if hdfs://big02.tedu.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/temp.db/log_hour is encrypted: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://big02.tedu.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/temp.db/log_hour, expected: hdfs://tbdp<br><br><br>
```

Can anyone help? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. The problem here is configuration of namenode.

You use:

```
hdfs://big02.tedu.com:8020/
```

But expected:

```
hdfs://tbdp
```

Grep you configs and change big02.tedu.com:8020 to tbdp